# redshift: how to unload to s3, and still get a resultset back

Tags: resultset, amazon-redshift

I have a query to redshift that gets unloaded to s3, that part is working fine. But it looks like the UNLOAD command does not return anything to my client app.

I want to avoid an extra call afterwards, from the client, to read the results from s3.

Is it possible do both: unload and still get a results set from redshift in one sql query?

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to run 2 statements; one to UNLOAD and one to SELECT the data for the client app.